# Who played with the Black Widow's mind?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, black-widow

In *Avengers* (2012), there is the following dialogue:

> NATASHA: Clint, you're gonna be alright.
>
> CLINT BARTON: You know that? Is that what you know? I got...I gotta go
> in though. I gotta flush him out.
>
> NATASHA: We don't have that long, it's gonna take time.
>
> CLINT BARTON: I don't understand. Have you ever had someone take your
> brain and play? Pull you out and send something else in? Do you know
> what it's like to be unmade?
>
> NATASHA: You know that I do.

Why does she say this? When and by whom was she "unmade"?

Comment: Confirmation will probably appear in the next movie, but it is highly suggested that before she joined shield she and other young girls were kidnapped and trained/brainwashed in to becoming assassins.

Comment: The Red Room...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

She’s referring to what they did to her in the Red Room. We learn a brief bit about it in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and considering the small scenes we see it is very suggested that there was a lot of brain washing going on.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** Neither can I. In the Red Room, where I was trained, where I was raised, um, they have a graduation ceremony. They sterilize you. It's efficient. One less thing to worry about. The one thing that might matter more than a mission. It makes everything easier. Even killing.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

This is confirmed in *Black Widow* where it's noted that Nat underwent psychological conditioning.

> **Yelena:** What you experienced was psychological conditioning.
>
> <sub>*Black Widow*</sub>

Comment: That doesn't sound to me like playing with her mine. They made her barren, they didn't hypnotize her...

Comment: @Wade making her barren was the final step. If you watch the scene with the flashback it’s clear there’s more to it than just that.

Comment: @Wade See the update. BW confirms that the Red Room was playing with her mind.